# Azure SDK List doesnt support filter option?

Tags: typescript, azure, sdk

I would like to get web app services with azure sdk(@azure/arm-appservice)

commonly, get somethings from list or anything. we can get something with index or filter. get by name or get by something... but azure sdk doesn't support any filter option.

just built-in level getByResourceGroup for webapps.

There are anyway to get webapps with some filter option?
I can get just list and filter on code level, but i dont like to do that. it is just limitation of azure sdk? i dont know why doesnt support any filter option...

Comment: you want to filter the web apps from a subscription or from the resource group?

Comment: just on subscription. now i just get all app services and just filtering on list

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built filter option for Azure SDK in typescript except for `ListByResourceGroup`.

you need to filter it on code level only.

For reference check this [GitHub doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/appservice/arm-appservice/samples/v14/typescript/src/webAppsListByResourceGroupSample.ts).

**#My code :**

```js
import {DefaultAzureCredential} from "@azure/identity";
import {KnownKind, WebSiteManagementClient} from "@azure/arm-appservice";

async function webapplist() {

const Sub_id = "b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    // Create the web client
    const webClient = new WebSiteManagementClient(credential, Sub_id);
    try {
        const list = new Array();
        let count = 0;
        for await(let item of webClient.webApps.list()){
               if(item.kind.startsWith('functionapp')){
                list.push(item);
                count++;
                if (count >= 2) {
                    break; 
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(list);
        }
    catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
    }
}
webapplist();
```

## `OUTPUT`:

```
[
  {
    id: '/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/py3func',
    name: 'py3func',
    kind: 'functionapp,linux',
    location: 'Australia East',
    type: 'Microsoft.Web/sites',
    tags: {
      'hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id': '/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/py3func',
    ////...... REDACTED......////
  },
  {
    id: '/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/signalrwithkv',
    name: 'signalrwithkv',
    kind: 'functionapp',
    location: 'Australia East',
    type: 'Microsoft.Web/sites',
    tags: {
      'hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id': '/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/components/signalrwithkv',
      ///...... REDACTED......///
  }
]
```

[image]

[image]